# Negative number format in kendo ui jquery and change color

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have written my project with kendo ui jquery, currently the problem I have is that negative numbers are not displayed correctly please guide me

And also how to change the color if it is positive or negative

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewm56.png)